# Can I find Southwest flights on sites like Skyscanner?

Tags: usa, flight-search-engines, domestic-travel, southwest-airlines

Historically, Southwest Airlines' flights would never show up on aggregate flight search engines like Skyscanner, Hipmunk, Expedia, etc. So when flying from city A to city B within the US, my process has always been:

1. Search on Skyscanner, Momondo, Hipmunk, etc.
2. Search on Southwest Airlines' website.

Today I was in the process of doing just that, and I [searched Skyscanner](https://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/bwi/dtta/170110/cheap-flights-from-baltimore-washington-international-to-detroit.html?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&qp_prevProvider=ins_month&qp_prevCurrency=GBP&qp_prevPrice=35&priceSourceId=unspecified-unspecified#results) for flights from BWI to Detroit on 10 January 2017. To my surprise, I found search results for Southwest!

Is this a Skyscanner-only perk, a quirk of timing, or can I now rely on being able to find Southwest fares on sites other than [Southwest](https://www.southwest.com/)'s? (And, eg, remove step 2 from my travel planning process above.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least Kayak is able to show Southwest flights, but isn't able to show their price:

[image]

I therefore presume they're not fully integrated into flight search systems and therefore you should always double check Southwest's website in case their flights don't show up.

Comment: In particular, this means that if you sort by price (which is the default on Kayak), you won't see Southwest flights at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Skyscanner will allow you to view if there is a Southwest flight available. However, sometimes the price may not be shown and you would need to click through to the Southwest site itself.

[image: Skyscanner Southwest Search Result]